# How to handle async Task Exception?

Tags: c#

How to handle async Task Exception?

I have a async Task Main class that calls on many async Tasks that parse from CSV and construct DTO with the data retrieved from the CSV. What I want to do is to handle the exceptions when it fails to parse for example like a DateTime is null, and like when I try to connect to a server that times out.

How should I handle the exception in a async Task method?

Should I put a "master" exception handler in the Main Class that handles all the exceptions returned from the tasks it calls, or should I handle the exception in each task itself? Like for the CSV parsing exception, I would like to return the error with the CSV filename it fails to parse, or if the I try to connect to a server and it fails to connect, I would like to return the server name in the exception.

How would you handle the exceptions? Would you do it in the Root level in the Main Class that calls on all the async tasks, or would you handle the exception in the task itself?

Another Scenario would be if the async Main class call on a async Task OpenReaderFilePath and it also calls for a async task ParseFromReader(). Let's say that the ParseFromReader get's an exception, and I want to return the exception with the object causing the exception to OpenReaderFilePath because I want to handle the exception with the object and the filepath it is occcuring for, how should I do this?

Comment: As long as you're actually capturing the exceptions and nothing is getting lost, this sounds somewhat like a matter of preference. I'd probably lean toward catching the exceptions in the outer method just because that avoids having to add logging to the inner methods. If you can add less logging code but the result is that you still get all of the information, that *might* be better.

Comment: I feel like this might just come down to preferences. Non the less, you always need to think "can I fix the error here?" If not, you should throw again (or not even catch it) to make it bubble up the calling tree. As soon as you know what to do in response to that exception, you should handle it. That however is my opinion and depending on severity, count, etc it's also acceptable to let everything bubble up and be handled by one "big" try/catch.

Comment: I agree "if you can handle & fix it inline, then that is best". However with some errors you need to punt, which might mean signaling the other tasks to give-up.  Generally, if you handle it from a single central place, it might be easier to handle (log, resolve, cancel) consistently.  But that all depends on whether consistent handling makes sense.

Comment: Since you have nested `await` calls in an `async` method " in Main class" then this method wont finish until all awaited tasks are finished, so handling your exception in that method of Main class is the best place.

Comment: @ScottHannen What does outer method mean? Is it possible to get an example? What I would like is to log to DB, but I would like to include some objects which is to be found in those different async tasks, like the filepath when I'm opening the data, and the object that is causing it. Like in cases where I tried to find a mapping that does not exist in "where" linq, is it possible to just skip the element that causes the exception and move on to the next element in the foreach list?

Comment: @Joelius I got a situation where I tried to to retrieve a value from a mapping cache by using name and ID of the element when I'm looping through a list with foreach. What happens is that the name is empty and it can't find the mapping in a where condition on a list and causes an exception. How would you handle this? Because what I want to do, is to just continue and process the next element in the foreach loop like "no exception happened" and it just skips the element in the foreach list that caused the exception.

Comment: By "inner" method I meant the task, and by "outer" method the method that invokes the task. I agree, that's not obvious. IOW, if we have private methods or internal classes that might throw exceptions, I'd lean towards letting them throw those exceptions without logging and having the public classes and methods log them. That way there's not logging in every single class and method but we still get all the information we need. But that's a generalization. A lot depends on specifics, and the question leaves some room for us to wonder what the actual scenario is.

Comment: In your last sentence it's not clear what is calling what. Is `main` calling both things, or is `main` calling `OpenReaderFilePath` and `OpenReaderFilePath` calls `ParseFromReader`?

Comment: main calling OpenReaderFilePath and OpenReaderFilePath calls ParseFromReader was supposed to be my last sentence.